# Need to extract value from the JSON Response which is not start from curly braces

Tags: json, jmeter, json-extract

I have below JSON response from the request. I'm aware how to extract value from the response using JSON Extractor but here I have different json response without stating curly braces and it start from string OK. I tried wildcard operator but didn't get any result.  I want to extract value 14869 from this response.

```
OK
[
    [
        [
            14869,
            8708,
            5032,
            463863,
            "AssignmentCardLearning",
            "{\"type\": \"AssignmentCardRefreshDone\", \"value\": {\"byEducator\": true}}",
            "{\"openTime\": 1701326839556, \"finishTime\": 1701326994605, \"postponeData\": null, \"lastTimeOpened\": 1702469689831, \"lastTimeOpenedBy\": {\"type\": \"AssignmentCardOpenedByUser\", \"value\": {}}, \"availabilityDatesM\": null, \"previousFinishTime\": null}",
            "{\"tags\": [{\"type\": \"AssignmentCardGracePeriodNotified\", \"value\": {\"closed\": false}}], \"loIds\": [], \"language\": null, \"practiceSetLOs\": [], \"packageTopicsIds\": [5032]}",
            0,
            "2023-11-30 06:47:14",
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Any technical info? Coding language?

Comment: It's JSON response buddy. I want to extract value 14869 from this.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't JSON. JSON would have identifiers. And my question is, how do you want to extract it? or where? I assume you are writing code in a coding language to extract the 'JSON'

Comment: This is invalid JSON. At best, you can treat it as a text/plain, aka a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON can begin with `[` as well in case of [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

In particular your case you can do it in 2 steps:

1. Remove this line containing `OK` by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and using the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code in it:

   ```
   prev.setResponseData(prev.getResponseDataAsString().substring(prev.getResponseDataAsString().indexOf('[')),'UTF-8')
   ```
2. Once done you should be able to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and the following [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query:

   ```
   $[0][0][0]
   ```

Demo:

[image]